# Does using(HttpResponseMessage) == Response.End (.Redirect) Getting ...code is optimized or a native frame

Tags: c#

I am getting this error and Google / SO makes it pretty clear this error is specific to using Response.Redirect or Response.End

> {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Microsoft specifically describes this as "by design" and suggest using a better method for achieving the desired effect [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629/en-us)

The code I am helping to troubleshoot does NOT use the indicated techniques such as Response.End but is does have a using statement so I'm wondering if the compiler translates the using into one of the undesirable calls such as Response.End?

Here is the snip where the error starts:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = HelperBuildRequest( client, "abc/123", HttpMethod.Get, ssoToken, "application/vnd.widgets.search.product-v1.0+json" );

using ( HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync( request ).Result )
{
   Action<SearchProductsResponseModel> action = ( result ) =>
   {
      .....doing stuff...
   };
  json = HelperResponse<SearchProductsResponseModel>( response, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, action );
}
```

When I wrap it with a try catch I get the same thing...I was hoping for something more specific.

So does anyone know how the compiler implements the using or perhaps the interaction between the using and the System.Action delegate or... really any other ideas?

TIA

OK so back from doing other stuff and following usr suggestion I trapped the error and looked in locals to see what migh present and YOWSER.

Absolutely I was NOT using the debugger to the full extent for this problem. The screen shot will make it all clear.

[image]

So usr make your comment an answer and I mark it right away.

THANK YOU

Comment: In what line does the error occur? This is not an exception, it's debugger output. Find the actual exception and post its ToString.

Comment: It happens on running the action delegate. I understand it is debugger output. I wrapped a try catch around the USING and got the same thing....the ...optimized..native frame...blah. Are you saying that what I should do is wrap the Action with try catch and see if I get something more specific.

Comment: You're probably not using the debugger correctly... Usually you can obtain the exception. Look into the locals window or post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exception, it's debugger output. Look into the locals window or post a screenshot. Update: Indeed, you have found the error that way.

> I was NOT using the debugger to the full extent for this problem

Yes.